# Manifest-declared broadcast receiver does not receive custom broadcast on Android 8

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

First, I created a `BroadcastReceiver` with empty body. Then, I added it to the AndroidManifest.xml. But I found out that `BroadcastReceiver` declared in manifest does not receive any broadcast. I sent broadcast by

```
sendOrderedBroadcast(new Intent("com.example.action"), null)
```

or

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.example.action
```

Both methods works on Android 7 but it does not work on Android 8. However, if the `BroadcastReceiver` is declared through `registerReceiver`, then it can still receive the broadcast.

On the other hand, `android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` works fine on both Android 7 and 8.

I want to ask why does it happen? I have tested it in both emulator and a physical device. They have the same behavior.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
...
<receiver
    android:name=".device.UsbBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        <action android:name="com.example.action" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
        android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
</receiver>
...
```

Comment: Implicit broadcasts are restricted as of Oreo. For most, you can only register Receivers dynamically on a `Context`, not statically in the manifest. However, there are certain exceptions, and that USB broadcast is one of them: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html.

Comment: @MikeM. I feel I am so stupid now and I spent several hours on debugging this. I am able to receive custom broadcast if I `setPackage` on my `Intent`. If you would like to write an answer, I will accept it. Otherwise, I will the others.

Comment: We've all been there. :-) I'm good. You can accept the posted answer. Thanks, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As part of the Android 8.0 (API level 26) Background Execution Limits, apps that target the API level 26 or higher can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest.

[Read this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html)

Comment: I got receiver registered for 3 custom actions in the Manifest, but it still doesn't get called. Am I missing something? According to the docs, it should work just fine with the custom actions.

Comment: @MarošŠeleng Try registering them inside activity also

Comment: try to add intent.SetClass(context, YourReceiverClass.class)

Answer (score 0):

**Manifest Based broadcast working for me in android 8**

Broadcast restriction by android is not applicable for all the broadcasts some can still be registered inside manifest . But do check latest documentation since these may way depending on android version .

```
 <receiver
            android:name=".UsbReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
```